# I'm trying to create a duplication tool in Maya using Python, but I keep getting the error message

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to create a duplication tool in Maya as part of learning more about Python. I managed to do it just through script, but I wanted to create a editable window, which would define the random generation seed and the amount of duplicatable objects(in this case I called them shields). However the only thing I'm getting is "# Error: invalid syntax # " so far. I would appreciate any help or explanation, thanks!

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import random

def createUI(pWindowTitle, pApplyCallback):
    
    windowID = 'myWindowID'
    
    if cmds.window( windowID, exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI (windowID)
        
    cmds.window( windowID, title=pWindowTitle, sizeable=True, resizeToFitChildren=True)
    
    cmds.rowColumnLayout (numberOfColumns=3, columnWidth=[ (1,75), (2,60), (3, 60)], columnOffset=[ (1,'right', 3) ] )
    
    cmds.text( label='Random Seed:')
    
    seedNumber = cmds.intField( minValue=0, maxValue=10000, value=0 )
    
    cmds.separator (h=10, style='none')
    
    cmds.text( label='Shield Amount:')
    
    shieldAmount = cmds.intField( minValue=0, maxValue=1000, value=0 )
    
    cmds.separator (h=10, style='none')
    
    cmds.separator (h=10, style='none')
    cmds.separator (h=10, style='none')
    cmds.separator (h=10, style='none')
    
    cmds.separator (h=10, style='none')
    
    cmds.button( label='Apply', command=functools.partial( pApplyCallback,
                                                  seedNumber,
                                                  shieldAmount) )
    
    def cancelCallback(*pArgs):
        if cmds.window( windowID, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI (windowID)
    
    cmds.button( label='Cancel', command=cancelCallback)
    
    cmds.showWindow()
    
def ShieldCreation (pSeedNumber, pShieldAmount)
    random.seed (pSeedNumber)

    result = cmds.ls( orderedSelection = True)

    transformName = result[0]

    instanceGroupName = cmds.group( empty=True, name = transformName + '_instance_grp#')

    for i in range( 0, pShieldAmount):

        instanceResult = cmds.instance( transformName, name = transformName + '_instance#')
    
        cmds.parent ( instanceResult, instanceGroupName )
    
        x = random.uniform(-10, 10)
        y = random.uniform(0, 20)
        z = random.uniform(-10, 10)
    
        cmds.move( x, y, z, instanceResult)
    
        xRot = random.uniform(0, 360)
        yRot = random.uniform(0, 360)
        zRot = random.uniform(0, 360)
    
        cmds.rotate( xRot, yRot, zRot, instanceResult)
    
        scalingFactor = random.uniform (0.3, 1.5)
    
        cmds.scale( scalingFactor, scalingFactor, scalingFactor, instanceResult)
    
    cmds.hide (transformName)

    cmds.xform( instanceGroupName, centerPivots = True)
    result: [u'pCylinder1']    

def applyCallback ( pSeedNumber, pShieldAmount, *Args):
    
    seedNumber = cmds.intField( pSeedNumber, query=True, value=True)
    
    shieldAmount = cmds.intField( pShieldAmount, query=True, value=True)
 
    selectionList  = cmds.ls( selection = True, type = 'transform' )

createUI( 'My Title', applyCallback)
```

Comment: Your syntax at `result: [u'pCylinder1']  ` is invalid - you can't assign it like this. If you want to set the value then do `result = [u'pCylinder1']`.

Comment: @dmitryro Thanks for pointing that out! It seems out of place, so I deleted it and I realized that I did not import the 'functools', but even after that it still gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Also replace `def ShieldCreation (pSeedNumber, pShieldAmount)` with `def ShieldCreation(pSeedNumber, pShieldAmount):`  - add the colon sign `:` so it becomes `):` that is missing there at `line 45` of your code.

Comment: @dmitryro I fixed the syntax. The window now pops up, but nothing happens, so I may have miassigned something.

Comment: There's a Python console there where you can run your functions, so `createUI( 'My Title', applyCallback)` in your last line should be called - you probably want to see if you can manually call it and what happens when you do call it.

Comment: @dmitryro Ok, so I managed to fix it!

in

`selectionList  = cmds.ls( selection = True, type = 'transform' )

createUI( 'My Title', applyCallback)`

I added 

`selectionList  = cmds.ls( selection = True, type = 'transform' )
    
    for objectName in selectionList:
        
        ShieldCreation (pSeedNumber, pShieldAmount)

createUI( 'My Title', applyCallback)`

Which worked but my seed wouldn't function, that was fixed by putting instead of `for i in range( 0, pShieldAmount):` I changed `for i in (pShieldAmount)`

Thank you so much for your help!